# how to create unkown amount of threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, client, server

I wrote a server c++ that connect to clients and i want to use thread in order to do some actions and with some clients and not to do only one client finish and go to another client. but i cant create unknown amount of theards only specific.
can sombody help me?

```
while (1)
{
    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL); // Accept a client socket
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) //Check for errors
    {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    else
    {
        t->join();
        std::thread t(&Manager::acceptance, this,ClientSocket,ListenSocket);
        t.join();
    }
}
```

and in the acceptnce i have the recv and send functions.
but it work only with one thread and i dont know how to create thread every time sombody will enter.
Thank you!
Nir

Comment: You are probably looking for a word other than "unknown".

Comment: You can keep a `vector` of all the threads you've created if you want.

Comment: i mean unlimited, when sombody enter my server i will create a new theard for him

Comment: The thread-per-client model turns out to scale quite poorly. You really want to create a thread pool, and push tasks into a queue that's serviced by the pool. This allows you to tune the number of threads to fit the processor(s) available.

Comment: If you want to, there's nothing stopping you from creating threads dynamically (just like you can create integers dynamically in a `std::vector<int>`). But it's not necessarily a good idea for a server. You probably want thread pool and/or non-blocking I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably doing the `t.join();` in order to avoid that your thread gets killed prematurely when the `std::thread` object `t` runs out of scope at the end of the `else` branch. But this way, your main thread is blocked and you cannot create another thread.

A better way to keep the thread alive is creating the `std::thread` object in a `std::list` or a `std::map` instead of a scoped local variable. This way you still control it, but your thread won't get terminated prematurely:

```
std::list<std::thread> workers;
// ...
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) //Check for errors
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    workers.push_back(std::thread(&Manager::acceptance, this, ClientSocket, ListenSocket));
}
```

Comment: can i do it in vector?

Comment: @user3346907: A `vector` is fine, too.

Comment: @user3346907: The code, as I posted it, is already "using it" in the sense of "starting the threads". The `join` is not necessary for that, the constructor does it already.

Comment: oh i think i get it, so in acceptance function do i need to do special things in order to use the thread? or just recv and send and everything will work

Comment: @user3346907: I don't know what you do in `acceptance`, but from what I see it is very likely that it still works the same way as before.

Comment: yes i just check it, it still stay in the thread of the first client that enterd and just after i finish with him its go to the second client (i dont want it )

Comment: @user3346907: You have to use *only* `ClientSocket` (*not* `ListenSocket`) in the function `acceptance`. And make sure you get rid of all the `join` calls.

Comment: i got rid from ListenSocket and from all the join calls but it still do one client and when it ends it do the secend one, mabey because inside the acceptance there is while with recv? because all what i want is to recv from both clients, but i can only after i finish the function (after the first client leave)

Comment: @user3346907: Just tested it, to make sure. It works like a charm. The problem must be somewhere else. If you need more help, post your code somewhere.

Comment: its work, but when i send the function like a function in class it dont work, like this:threads.push_back(std::thread(&Manager::connection, ClientSocket)); it dont work
but like this :threads.push_back(std::thread(&connection, ClientSocket)); it work, but i must use it in the class what should i do?

Comment: @user3346907: If you pass a class method as function, you have to pass a pointer to the object as argument. In your case it would be a pointer to the `Manager` object. In many cases it will be `this` (use it like this: `threads.push_back(std::thread(&connection, this, ClientSocket));`), but that depends on if the code that creates the thread is in the same class or not.

Comment: @user3346907: I meant, of course: `threads.push_back(std::thread(&Manager::connection, this, ClientSocket));`

Comment: i just send the server to my teacher, thank you so much! every thing work great!